# Plotly Dash Graph Inputs to the Right of Graph

Tags: django, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a plotly graph with input boxes on top.

[image]

Is there a way to send these input boxes to the right of the graph. I have checked the documentation but it doesn't seem to mention this in the `dcc.Input` section.
https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/input

```
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Input(
            id = "input_{}".format(_),
            type = _,
            placeholder="input type {}".format(_),
        )
        for _ in ALLOWED_TYPES
    ]
    + [dcc.Graph(id='graph', figure=fig, style={'width': '90vh', 'height': '90vh'})]
)
```

`dcc.Input` doesn't seem to have an option for this.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just configure a CSS property for this via the `style` prop on `dcc.Input`? (e.g. `style={ "float": "right" }`)

Comment: I tried and it offset a few things but it looks like that was totally the way to do it. Thanks so much for the help! If you want to post an answer go ahead!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `style` prop of `dcc.Input` to align the input elements with CSS.

```py
dcc.Input(
  ...
  style={"float": "right"},
)
```

Or if you want a bit more control with how the input elements are positioned, you could always use Flexbox. That would involve setting the `style` prop on the outer `html.Div` such that `display: flex`, and then you can use flex properties for the input elements.